# Bash script with cURL; not sending POST as JSON

Tags: json, bash, rest, curl, urlencode

I'm creating a simple bash script to run a cURL POST command.
The script, even though it is the same command does not send the POST data as json.

### When I enter the command by hand it sends the POST data as JSON with no problem.

```
$ curl --include --header 'Accept:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' --data '{"sourceTemplateId":111111111111111}' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' https://api.everbridge.net/rest/notifications/000000000000000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 18:13:15 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "message" : "OK",
  "id" : 5748251085623370,
  "baseUri" : "https://api.everbridge.net/rest/notifications/000000000000000/",
  "instanceUri" : "https://api.everbridge.net/rest/notifications/000000000000000/5748251085623370"
}
```

### When I run an echo for my bash script, I get this.

```
$ ./Send_Not.sh
curl --include --header 'Accept:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' --data '{"sourceTemplateId":111111111111111}' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' https://api.everbridge.net/rest/notifications/000000000000000
```

***Literally the same format***

### But when I run the script, I get this error.

```
$ ./Send_Not.sh
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 18:28:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "status" : 415,
  "message" : "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported"
```

**Here is my script, it's super simple.**

```
#!/bin/bash
ajson=\'Accept:application/json\'
credentials=\'Authorization:Basic\ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\'
data=\'{\"sourceTemplateId\":111111111111111}\'
CT=\'Content-Type:application/json\'
url="https://api.everbridge.net/rest/notifications/000000000000000"

curl --include --header "$ajson" --header "$credentials" --data "$data" --header "$CT" "$url"
```

**Reran the command with -X POST and -v**

```
$ ./Send_Not.sh
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1108 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 54.193.84.167...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1161 (connection #0)
* Connected to api.everbridge.net (54.193.84.167) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1260 (connection #0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1274 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Glendale; O=Everbridge; OU=SaaS Operations; CN=*.everbridge.net
*  start date: Sep 18 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 17 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.everbridge.net" matched cert's "*.everbridge.net"
*  issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x600057830; line 1295 (connection #0)
> POST /rest/notifications/000000000000000 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.everbridge.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
> Accept: */*
> 'Accept:application/json'
> 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
> 'Content-Type:application/json'
> Content-Length: 39
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 39 out of 39 bytes
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x600057830; line 1357 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x600057830; line 1484 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x600057830; line 1494 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
* Server nginx/1.8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.8.0
Server: nginx/1.8.0
< Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 21:08:12 GMT
Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 21:08:12 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
{
  "status" : 415,
  "message" : "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported"
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x600057830; line 1652 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
* Connection #0 to host api.everbridge.net left intact
}
```

**Echo with new script suggested by Mircea**

```
$ ./Send_Not.sh
curl -vvv --include --header 'Accept:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -X POST --data '{"sourceTemplateId":111111111111111}' --header Content-Type:application/json https://api.everbridge.net/rest/notifications/000000000000000
```

**Reply when I execute new script**

```
$ ./Send_Not.sh
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1108 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 54.193.84.167...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1161 (connection #0)
* Connected to api.everbridge.net (54.193.84.167) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1260 (connection #0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1274 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Glendale; O=Everbridge; OU=SaaS Operations; CN=*.everbridge.net
*  start date: Sep 18 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 17 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.everbridge.net" matched cert's "*.everbridge.net"
*  issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x600057830; line 1295 (connection #0)
> POST /rest/notifications/000000000000000 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.everbridge.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
> Accept: */*
> 'Accept:application/json'
> 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 39
>
* upload completely sent off: 39 out of 39 bytes
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x600057830; line 1357 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x600057830; line 1484 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x600057830; line 1494 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
* Server nginx/1.8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.8.0
Server: nginx/1.8.0
< Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 21:41:01 GMT
Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 21:41:01 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
{
  "status" : 400,
  "message" : "Error Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.tools.ant.filters.StringInputStream@5d5906fc; line: 1, column: 2] parsing input:\n'{\"sourceTemplateId\":111111111111111}'"
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x600057830; line 1652 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
* Connection #0 to host api.everbridge.net left intact
}
```

**I also escaped the double quotes for Conten-Type, and I got the original error**

```
#!/bin/bash
ajson="Accept:application/json"
credentials="Authorization:Basic xxxx_replace_xxxx"
data='{"sourceTemplateId":111111111111111}'
CT=\"Content-Type:application/json\"
url="https://api.everbridge.net/rest/notifications/000000000000000"

curl -vvv --include --header "$ajson" --header "$credentials" --data "$data" --header "$CT" "$url"
```

**Original error when executed**

```
$ ./Send_Not.sh
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1108 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 54.193.84.167...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1161 (connection #0)
* Connected to api.everbridge.net (54.193.84.167) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1260 (connection #0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057830; line 1274 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Glendale; O=Everbridge; OU=SaaS Operations; CN=*.everbridge.net
*  start date: Sep 18 00:00:00 2015 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 17 23:59:59 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.everbridge.net" matched cert's "*.everbridge.net"
*  issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x600057830; line 1295 (connection #0)
> POST /rest/notifications/000000000000000 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.everbridge.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.48.0
> Accept: */*
> 'Accept:application/json'
> 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
> "Content-Type:application/json"
> Content-Length: 39
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 39 out of 39 bytes
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x600057830; line 1357 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x600057830; line 1484 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x600057830; line 1494 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
* Server nginx/1.8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.8.0
Server: nginx/1.8.0
< Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 21:48:54 GMT
Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 21:48:54 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
{
  "status" : 415,
  "message" : "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported"
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x600057830; line 1652 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
* Connection #0 to host api.everbridge.net left intact
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to write the `curl` command directly in the bash script, without variables nor quotes, just to check? Once you get it running this way, modify it by replacing the strings by quoted variables, by only one by one, to find where the problem comes from.

Comment: Your curl is lacking the `-X POST` parameter isnt it? Also, your header is partitionated, can you try using as a single message, to see its a problem... Finally, check if your cURL is updated, check the version, and the parametters it expect. Edit your question with a `-v` reply

Comment: @zezollo Yes, I've tested it with just the curl command directly in the bash script and it works.

Comment: @Bonatti I've added reply with -X POST and -v...

Comment: this is most likely a problem with the way you escape the parameters. Look at the verbose form and you will see 2 content types: > 'Content-Type:application/json'
> Content-Length: 39
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @SongJaeGu - You should review how [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) works in shell scripting. If you run `echo 'foo'`, then `echo` receives one parameter with the value `foo` (unquoted).  However `a=\'foo\'; echo "$a"` will have the same output as `echo "'foo'"` which receives one parameter with the value `'foo'` (single quotes retained).

Comment: @Mr.Llama I understand that and I've tried all variations of quoting and I'm still unsuccessful.

Comment: So, why don't you try to use only one variable at a time, just to find out where your problem comes from? For instance, run the same (almost) raw command from your bash script, only turning the first header into a variable: `curl --include --header "$ajson" --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'...` (the rest of strings remaining directly hard coded for the first test). Then try with the second one, then with data, etc. you'll find out for sure. I also suspect the quoting to be wrong somewhere (especially the `"$data"` one). You may well have missed some possible quoting variation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments this is an issue on how you are escaping things.
Here is a form of the script that works:

```
#!/bin/bash
ajson="Accept:application/json"
credentials="Authorization:Basic xxxx_replace_xxxx"
data='{"sourceTemplateId":111111111111111}'
CT="Content-Type:application/json"
url="https://api.everbridge.net/rest/notifications/000000000000000"

curl -vvv --include --header "$ajson" --header "$credentials" --data "$data" --header "$CT" "$url"
```

Comment: I can't figure out to change text to code format in the comments, so I've added it up top in the original question.

Comment: you got the content type wrong (missing the quotes)